# How to completely rid a project of persisting EF6 provider references?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, visual-studio-2019

I have found it unexpectedly difficult to switch database providers in EF6. The consistent problem is that the project holds on to the old references even after they're completely removed.

Case in point: from time to time I need to switch from SQLCE to SQL and vice-versa. Inevitably the project will refuse to connect to the new database, offering an excuse that goes something like this:

> No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0'.

In this case, I'm trying to switch from SQLCE to SQL.

Things I've tried:

- Removed all SQLCE packages and related `Imports` statements
- Cleaned the project/solution
- Restarted Visual Studio
- Used TextPad to search the project folder/subfolder hierarchy for anything related to SQLCE, and removed anything found
- Deleted my `App.config` file (a clean new project without any `App.config` at all works just fine)
- Used this `App.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

- Used this code:

```
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.Data.Entity.SqlServer
Imports System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure

Friend Class DbProviderConfig
  Inherits DbConfiguration

  Public Sub New()
    Me.SetDefaultConnectionFactory(New SqlConnectionFactory(SqlProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName))
    Me.SetProviderServices(SqlProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName, SqlProviderServices.Instance)
  End Sub
End Class
```

- Deleted my `bin` and `obj` folders and rebuilt

Nevertheless, after all this, I still get the error:

> No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0'.

Where could that reference be? How can I update it to reflect the new SQL provider?

**--EDIT--**

I neglected to mention initially that I'm using Code First Migrations.

Comment: Updated the EDMX file?

Comment: Pardon me, I should have mentioned that I'm using Code First Migrations. I'll update my question.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce it?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I figured out where those trailing references are.

It looks like they're stored in the individual migration files themselves, in compiled/base64-encoded strings in the resource files (visible when we choose `Show All Files` for the project).

[image]

I had to:

1. Delete all migrations
2. Build the project (important step!)
3. Issue the `Add-Migration` command to generate one big initial migration for the new database

Once I did this, I was able to connect using the new provider (`SqlClient`, in this case).

At first I saw this as a shortcoming in EF, surmising that database portability was broken here. But I've since reconsidered.

The design makes sense; a given migration represents a history of what happened in that database. And everyone knows we can't change the past!

When we want to swap in a new database provider mid-stream, then, we'll use a second `DbContext`—at least temporarily—and then copy the data across in a separate step. We can't (and shouldn't) use one database's migrations for another.

Someone more familiar with the inner workings of the migration engine might be able to confirm all of this.

**--EDIT--**

Further testing indicates that this theory is incorrect. It worked once, but then no more.